# Will my .env variable value be exposed to clients?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I am using .env to store all my private Api_key value, which is to call third party API key like google map.

I was told that, with react js, the javascipt is actually excuted in client side.

Does it mean that actually, my .env variables are accessible by clients too in which they can actually see my API key?

For example, in my component code, I have this

```
<Geocoder
  mapRef={mapRef}
  mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_mapbox_key}
  position="top-left"
  placeholder="Set your position"
/>
```

In my .env

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_mapbox_key=<KEY>
```

If yes, how do I keep it safe while providing the key to the third party components

Comment: No, it is not accessible to others just put  your `.env` inside `gitignore` before publishing it   under `# misc
.env`

Comment: I understand putting it into gitignore would not push my .env code on github. But my confusion is that, 
since the .env.api_code variable will be populated on client side, then will they see it actually?

Comment: Well, if you use it in a react component, the component makes the connection to the remote api. Thus the component knows the key. Since the component is rendered on the client, the client knows the key.  But I wonder if `process.env` is available on the client.

Comment: If process.env.variable could be seen on clients side, then whether clients can access in process.env doesn't matter at all. Since the variable api key was exposed already. BUT Thanks for your explanation ^^

Comment: `process.env` isn't available on the client. Next.js replaces all delcarations like `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VAR` on the client with its actual value at build time.

Comment: I am doubt that it isnt available. If it is not isn't available on the client, how does the component make a connection to the remote API? With build, component can make a call without knowing the actual api key? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, users will be available to see your `API` key in network inspection, even if you will keep it in the `.env` file which is excluded from git.

It's better to make a separate route on your backend side and keep your API key on the backend - if it is possible.

Some useful links:

- [API security best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restrict_apikey)
- [5 best practices for secure API key storage](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/best-practices-api-key-storage)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, you bring out another question. Sometimes I found it quite confused with the terms "backend" Isnt it the place that stores my .env is backend already? Where should I put my code when .env is already in the backend.

Comment: Client - it is your react application; backend - it is your server.
Both client and backend can store variables in the .env file - because they are separate projects.
You can configure your CI/CD and store these variables, f.e. in project settings on GitLab or GitHub - as an example.

Comment: But isnt it that there was already a API folder inside the next js project? Why do we need another project? I always thought that project is backend already and client means what the users see on the browser. Sorry if this understanding is so wrong as I started learning this approach thru online class. Maybe there is aother perspective in the industry.

Comment: @hose You can also use Next.js API routes for your backend API. It all depends on the approach you take.

Comment: Backend is code running on your server/online cloud service. Frontend is what is shipped to client when he makes request.
Keeping API_KEY in backend help to avoid client contact with API_KEYS as client request server and server can read API_KEY and send a response back to client.
<br>
About Next.js, Its a full stack framework hence you can have server functions and client code in same project.